# Two Http Get methods in a single click event - MVC Razor jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This my click event. I am trying to perform two get methods in a single button events since my logical flow is cascading. The debugger jumps from point A to point B skipping the code in between. As a result `applicantArray` remains empty forever. I have no clue what is happening . Any ideas ? Help appreciated.

```
$("#appid").on("click", ".classname", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var url = 'A';     // point A
    $.get(url, { id: some id },
        function (data) {
            applicantArray.push(value_n); // globally declared
        });

        $.get('B', { value: some value}, // point B
        function (data) {
           //use applicationArray
        });
});
```

Comment: Put the 2nd `get` inside the callback for the 1st `get` ;)

Comment: Ajax is async. Use success callback in first get request, to call second get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not achieve cascading behaviour through ajax like this since applicantArray didnot populates untill first ajax call not returns. Cascading behaviour is achieved by calling the second ajax call on the first call success. like:

```
$("#appid").on("click", ".classname", function (evt) {
evt.preventDefault();
var url = 'A';     // point A
$.get(url, { id: some id },
    function (data) {

        applicantArray.push(value_n); // globally declared
        $.get('B', { value: some value}, // point B
            function (data) {
             //use applicationArray
         });
    });

    });
```